# Oracle : Partition script terminating without any error

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create partition on Oracle 11g database on a large table (over 5 billion rows).  I tried using TOAD and sqlplus from my local machine to connect to database and them running partition script. I am using CTAS to created another table similar to base table and then rename it to original (after dropping original table).

As table size is big (about 170G), I am expecting this to take few hrs. My query is running fine for about 2 hrs and then it disconnects without any error message. Even though I cannot see any session from backend, in Toad and sqlplus it still says that it is running. No message in alertlog or any log file.

I checked user profile and resource limits and it is set to unlimited. Also I cannot see anything unusual in database setting.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: your dba killed your session maybe?  I wouldn't run something like this in Toad though

Comment: DBA did not killed the session at all. Yes you are right, for this long running scripts, we should start in background or run on server using sqlplus.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the script directly on the server hosting database using sqlplus and it did finish after 5 hrs. Not terminated in between. Learned that, at server level - some setting was terminating oracle connection after 2 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

While you might be interesting in how to retrieve the logs and the error message of your previous run, I rather suggest, next time you try again, you should run long running operations as a background job in Oracle.

Take a look at the dbms_scheduler module: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php

Or, if you have an older version of Oracle, you can use the the dbms_job module http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_job.html